# How to access the url categoryid as setcategoryid in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

Can we access the url category id to setCategoryId field in the CMS page Layout xml (Magento)?

```
<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>3</category_id></action>
<action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>{ url_id }</category_id></action>
```

Comment: will pls give more info, what do you want to do >

Comment: If i give setCategoryd is 3, will be displayed products under cateogory 3 only...am using this cms page for displaying products another category also. i need to know how to replace this category (3) with another category ids, which is coming in urls....